# Nonregular Languages in Sublogarithmic Space

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-complexity

Are there any known languages that require $o(\log n)$ space but are also not regular?  I'm looking for a problem "just below" undirected connectivity.

Comment: Yes. You can check the book by Szepietowski (1994) http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-58355-6/page/1

Comment: @AbuzerYakaryilmaz maybe make this an answer ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat: I did :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. I think the main reference is [Turing Machines with Sublogarithmic Space](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-58355-6/page/1) by Szepietowski (1994). (Link to [books.google](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=3540583556))

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to read the book, take the numbers written in binary from 1 to n, separated by a comma.